# Python list view works with text files

Tags: python, listview, text-files

How to make list view in Python tkinter works with data in text files?
I want to open text file that may have contacts list in it.

For example:

```
Name Address Mobile Rate
```

And then layout those data in a list view.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

you can create the list in python as given below:

```
seq = L[name:number]

seq = L[::2] # get every other item, starting with the first
seq = L[::2] # get every other item, starting with the second
```

or you can directly go as mention below:

```
name = L[::2] # get every other item, starting with the first
number = L[1::2] # get every other item, starting with the second
```

if you wants to add any row you can add.
i will suggest you to go with first methode